# Printing forms on Play Framework

Tags: printing, playframework

I'm developing a web app, using Play framework and javascript, but exactly I don't know how to print a form (i.e. an invoice). I thought it has to be implemented on Javascript. but reading on web, I didn't find anything. I´m searching now if the implementation is on Server side (Java), but i dont have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very weird question that you have here, I probably don't get it right..

What do you mean "Print a form" ?!

What about **print page** from your favorite browser ?

Must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What about render the invoice in pdf format?If you are interested in doing something like that check this module:

http://www.playframework.org/modules/pdf

I think it is the best solution and that's what most companies do.Hope that helped